# Turn Multiple (M) Rows of (N) Columns into One Row with (M*N) Columns In Oracle

Tags: oracle

I've had a lot of trouble finding examples or information on this.  I've looked into `PIVOT` but the examples I've found left me a little confused as to what is actually going on.  I'm also not looking to sum or group the data.

Essentially, I have a query that returns 2 rows of 4 columns

```
A B C D
--------
1 2 4 8
2 4 8 0
```

And I want that look like

```
A B C D A2 B2 C2 D2
-------------------
1 2 3 4  2  4  8  0
```

Is this something I can accomplish without PL/SQL?

EDIT:  If there is a way to do this for a fixed number of rows and columns - I'd still welcome the answer to that approach.  Ideally, it would also work on SQL Server, but I'd be happy with an Oracle specific solution.

Comment: Will your query always return 2 rows of 4 columns (and thus the output will always be 1 row of 8 columns)?  Or are the M rows and N columns intended to be dynamic so that tomorrow you may get 3 rows and want 12 columns in the result?  How do you know which row from the original result goes in columns A,B,C,D of the result and which goes in A2,B2,C2,D2?

Comment: In my particular case it will always be between 0 and 6 rows.

Comment: Would it be acceptable, then, to always return a 24 column result set with some columns being NULL if there are fewer than 6 rows returned?  How do you know which row from the original result goes in columns A,B,C,D of the result and which goes in A2,B2,C2,D2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have mentioned that even a solution with fixed number of rows and columns is ok, you can try this...

```
SELECT MIN(DECODE(rownum, 1, A, null)) A,
       MIN(DECODE(rownum, 1, B, null)) B,
       MIN(DECODE(rownum, 1, C, null)) C,
       MIN(DECODE(rownum, 1, D, null)) D,
       MIN(DECODE(rownum, 2, A, null)) A2,
       MIN(DECODE(rownum, 2, B, null)) B2,
       MIN(DECODE(rownum, 2, C, null)) C2,
       MIN(DECODE(rownum, 2, D, null)) D2
FROM <test_table>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have never seen a mechanism to vary the number of columns in the result set based on the number of rows returned.  You might be able to dynamically generate a query based on the result set, then execute the query.

PIVOT tables are more about switching the X and Y coordinates.  I don't think this is what you are looking for.

Given you have a fixed maximum you could always return 6*N columns and use decode on rownum to select data into the appropriate columns.

Answer (score 1):

A select statement always needs to have a fixed number of columns determinable at parse time. What you are asking is to be able to determine the columns at fetch time.

Can't be done.